# Training detector without bounding box data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, unsupervised-learning, object-detection

From what I can see most object detection NNs (Fast(er) R-CNN, YOLO etc) are trained on **data including bounding boxes** indicating where in the picture the objects are localized.

Is there any model that can be trained with image+label data (**without bounding box data**) to predict the bounding box(es) ?

I am referring following papers

- [Is object localization for free? – Weakly Supervised Object
  Recognition with Convolutional Neural Networks](https://www.di.ens.fr/willow/research/weakcnn)
- [Self-taught object localization with deep networks](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7477688)

These papers are not recent and I am not able to find any recent papers related to this . Please let me know if there are any other resources related to available .

Thanks in advance

Comment: both links send me to the same place :o

Comment: Thanks for noticing @JérémyBlain ......Now it will send you to different place